# How would you find the impedance of this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, impedance

[image]

I am working on a project using C++ to find the impedance of a circuit.  In implementing the program I have realised that the program cannot find the impedance for a circuit of this type.

My intuitive method to find the impedance would be to find the impedance of R_SRC and C4 in parallel to R1, but then I am unsure how I would find the impedance of the second part as C4 is in the second branch, which is a situation ive never seen.

I know all the expressions for impedances of the individual components and how impedances add in parallel and series but am not sure how to apply that to this specific scenario.  Is there a way this circuit can be redrawn to have more of an intuitive layout?

My current logic to finding the impedance. Is this correct?

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Is this homework? What have you tried so far? Do you know how to do j-omega-transformation?

Comment: Please share your work.

Comment: I'll give you a useful tip - redrawing a circuit can show you things you may otherwise miss.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be homework, but fails to show what OP has attempted so far.

Comment: @GodJihyo In this case im unsure of how it would be redrawn to be more familiar to cases i know.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I have editted it to give more detail, it is not homework.

Comment: C4 is shorted and has no affect on the overall impedance. Perhaps you didn't draw the circuit correctly?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Thanks for the response, It wasnt drawn correctly, its been editted to be correct now.

Comment: @ryani42 That's what I was trying to get you to notice. I thought this might have been one of those trick circuits instructors like to give out where there's a component shorted but it's drawn in a way that doesn't make it obvious.

Comment: What algorithm are you currently using? If you're using Modified Nodal Analysis you should be able to just add the appropriate conductances to the corresponding matrix elements without regard to it not being cleanly "series" or "parallel"; if you're using a different algorithm then the answer may depend on other design decisions and assumptions you're making but haven't started.

Comment: @nanofarad The program is written ground up by me using standard c++ libraries. Its nothing fancy, just for the 3 components. The context was just so people didnt think i was trying to get answers for a homework, i simply want to know how you combine these impedances to find the total impedance of the circuit.

Comment: @ryani42 Even written from the ground up, you have a lot of latitude to choose different algorithms and approaches that you implement to solve this kind of circuit. MNA is both a plausible choice of algorithm and how I would do it personally, but there are other approaches (which you haven't specified) so that's why I asked to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there a way this circuit can be redrawn to have more of an
> intuitive layout?*

Yes there is: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBt0Jc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This redraw allows you to see what the impedance is at DC and at infinite frequency.

Then, to calculate the impedance vs frequency, I would convert V1, RSRC and R2 into its equivalent Thevenin circuit. I would also do the same with V1, R1 and L1 for the right hand path: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA9SV6.png)</sup>

This will tell you the current that flows through the capacitor C4 and will tell you the voltages on either side of C4. Of course it's just a start, but that's the way I'd go.

Or, just get hold of a simulator and let it do the heavy lifting.